# Make delimitMate and xmledit work together

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, xml-editor

I have both [delimitMate.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2754) and [xmledit.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=301) installed.

When I type a tag and `>` to close, an extra trailing `>` is entered.

What I type:

```
<p>
```

What I see:

```
<p></p>>
```

delimitMate completes `<` to `<>` placing the cursor in between.
Typing `p` creates the tag and typing `>` makes xmledit autocomplete the closing tag and place the cursor in between. However, an extra `>` is appended.

How can I prevent the extra `>` from appearing after the closing tag?

Comment: The plugins apparently don't work well together; open an issue (on both projects) to make them aware of that and kindly offer your help in developing a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XMLedit heavliy depended on the closing `>` to be manually typed. This is fixed here

https://github.com/sukima/xmledit/commit/8d72f6c606fbb238fa238aa8ac1ed887503727c5

Answer (score 1):

The xmledit plugin has a few options, so if you'd really want you could disable it's completion.

Put this in your `.vimrc`:

```
let xml_tag_completion_map = "<C-l>"
```

Now pressing `>` will no longer put two closing characters, and you can still trigger the (awesome!) nest-tag functionality by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> after the `>` character.

Comment: I was just about to suggest this in an answer, you beat me to it. Thanks. ~(xmlvim owner)

Comment: For some reason, it inserts a literal ^L in insert mode. It doesnt do anything in normal mode either

Comment: @user80551 Make sure you are in an XML, otherwise the xmledit plugin is not loaded. However, wasn't your problem more that you had double `>` characters?